# Regular Exp - match and replace all tags that don't equal x with html safe

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a chat program and what I want to do is replace all the html tags with > < tags but allow specific tags to still work (img, a etc.)

This is what I have so far but it does not appear to be working:

```
$value = '
<img src="/blah/blah.gif" />
<img src="/blah/blah.gif">
<b>blah</b>
<strong>test</strong>
<script>test</script>
<script>test
<script
type="text">

<script></script>
<script
>

</script>

<script>blah

<br />

';
$tags = 'b|img'; // allow these tags

echo preg_replace("~<((/(?!$tags)|(?!/)(?!$tags)).*?)>~is", '&lt;$1&gt;', $value);
```

The result of the output is this:

```
<img src="/blah/blah.gif" />
<img src="/blah/blah.gif">
<b>blah</b>
&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;script&gt;test&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script&gt;test
&lt;script
type="text"&gt;

&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script
&gt;

&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;script&gt;blah

<br />
```

As you can see it doesn't appear to be stripping the 
 tag out as well even though this is not in the `$tags` variable as an allowed tag.

Comment: I'll just leave it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I'm not trying to strip the tags out, I want them to be there, but replace them with html entities so they still display but don't read as html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = '
<img src="/blah/blah.gif" />
<img src="/blah/blah.gif">
<b>blah</b>
<strong>test</strong>
<script>test</script>
<script>test
<script
type="text">

<script></script>
<script
>

</script>

<script>blah

<br />

';

echo strip_tags($value,'<b><img>');
```

echoes:

```
<img src="/blah/blah.gif" />
<img src="/blah/blah.gif">
<b>blah</b>
test
test
test







blah
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually advise to replace all HTML tags to `&lt;`/`&gt;` unconditionally, and then introduce BBCode support: it will save you from an incredible amount of headache.

As for the original question, the only way I know of to do this reliably is to parse input HTML, throw away all redundant whitespaces and then do pattern-matching.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to do is replace it on the server side, say if a user puts a url to an image http://image.com/blah.jpg it would recognize it on the server and replace it with <img src="">. The user won't be aware of the changes so they don't need to learn BBCode.

Comment: Hm, some sites actually do this: if you want to place a picture in your message, you just type its URL there. The site finds an URL in your text, sees that it ends in ".jpg" or something - and places an `img` tag around it. Now the user won't need to know even HTML.